# fe_sendauth: no password supplied Ruby On Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby

Voy a subir un proyecto de Rails a Heroku por lo tanto el proyecto esta en Postgres pero al probarlo en desarrollo (No en produccion) me sale este error:
PG::ConnectionBad
fe_sendauth: no password supplied

En mi archivo database lo tengo asi:

```
>development:
>> <<: *default
>>>database: mubi_development
>>>>username: mubi
>>>>>password: password
```

Comment: Mueve la entrada de password al mismo nivel que username

Answer (score 1):

Recuerda que los archivos *YAML* se basan en la indentación de sus elementos, por lo que es importante tener todos correctamente alineados en su respectivo nivel.

`database.yml` utiliza solo dos niveles:

1. El ambiente para el que se proporciona la configuración de BD.
2. Los atributos de configuración de la BD.

En tu caso, el código que muestras debería modificarse para quedar así:

```
development:
  <<: *default
  database: mubi_development
  username: mubi
  password: password
```